# Will large strings, instead of auto-increment numbers, as ids affect my database performance?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am currently developing a web application, where the front-end and the application logic is entirely based in Javascript and I use PHP only for the transactions with the backend (MySQL).

Since I create complicated and interconnected objects in Javascript that will later be translated into multiple database records I need to have a unique identity for them (Id) that is generated in Javascript. I cannot overcome this and send requests to the database in order to ask for the next unique key in a table and commit it, cause as I said the object creation is rather complicated and I would have to have multiple nested AJAX requests.

Anyway if I change the Primary Key of some tables from INT to VARCHAR(32) is it going to have an impact in the performance?

Note the keys are in the form of: 
timestamp-zeroes_userid-zeroes_incremetedid ex. (1373222220000000001000000014)

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to @Gordon's answer, make sure you create an index on these string-ID fields. That will help performance too.

Comment: As I said to @Gordon I will try to find a way to skip Javascript's generated ids and use MySQL's auto-incremented ids via multiple AJAX requests. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The increased size of the keys increases the size of the indexes and the pages used to store data.  This results in fewer records per data page and more reads to get data into memory.

For a single key in a single table, increasing from 4 to 32 bytes probably won't have a major impact on performance.  But if you have an additional cost of 28 bytes for every foreign key reference -- and you have even tens of foreign key references in the database -- then the larger data size will start to impede performance.

In this case, you should store the original key in the original data but also create an auto-incremented integer primary key.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is quite clear that I have to find a way to use database ids instead of Javascript's. Perhaps with multiple AJAX requests, something that I wanted to avoid... Thanks anyway!